# Invoke function on each element of collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

We have a list of cars - `List<Car>`

```
Car{
     String name;
     String year;
     String getName(){ return name;}
     String getYear(){ return year;}
     ...
......
}
```

For each car in the list,we would need to call function isVintage(String carName,.....).
All cars which return true for the above check need to be collected into a list.
Is this possible using Streams?

Comment: Easily. Take a look at the [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please remember to do at least a little research before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like below:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(car -> isVintage(car.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming, `list` is the list of cars.